# Normalizing my nested JSON with normalizr

Tags: javascript, json, normalizr

I'm having the following JSON from my service:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Voter1",
      "id":1,
      "votingCard":{  
         "verificationCodes":[  
            "3I08jA",
            "3x0eyE",
            "2_i69I"
         ],
         "votingCode":"7zCOelDnjfBm7TtFydc4QodgonG",
         "finalizationCode":"jyYu",
         "confirmationCode":"4ACfcpBVH45iAXqg7hJ0tbEe_tV"
      }    
   },
    .....
   {  
      "id":5,
      "name":"Voter5",
      "votingCard":{  
         "verificationCodes":[  
            "2c9I9a",
            "3bEeEa",
            "1gPKx2"
         ],
         "confirmationCode":"4Z7wNG35VR2UMO6-W-0aZVEhbLM",
         "votingCode":"6YQ2x-c8LXJZF05gh3zTajU79ct",
         "finalizationCode":"S0CY"
      }
   }
]
```

And would like to get it normalized, so a list of votingCards and a list of voters with a "votingCard" property referencing the votingCard by id.

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

const votingCard = new schema.Entity('votingCard');

const voter = new schema.Entity('voter', {
    votingCard: votingCard,
});

const votersSchema = new schema.Array(voter);


const mutations = {
    SOCKET_SYNCVOTERS: (state, data) => {
        var input = JSON.parse(data);
        const normalizedData = normalize(input, votersSchema);
        console.log(normalizedData);
    },
};
```

However, I'm not getting what I want:

Why is there an "undefined"?

[image]

Comment: you're not showing us the same json node in the above source code

Comment: Hmmm what do you mean? The picture shows the output of `console.log(normalizedData);` while the first JSON listing is from `console.log(data);`. Have I missed something?

Comment: In the image you've published, the one with the error is "Voter5" and instead of "name" property it seems to have a "voter" property. In the beginning of your question show us how Voter5 is defined in your json. It might be a problem with that specific node.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify an ‘idAttribute’ in the options for the votingCard entity - the problem is that normalizr can’t find an ‘id’ field in those objects so they are all being picked up as id undefined and overwriting each other in entities.  See: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#schema

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem! Adding some "id" field to the voting cards fixed the issue.